# IE | How to prevent input-focus missing on scrolling page?

Tags: javascript, html

I have HTML form with a lot of inputs. I'm interesting in situation when I have focused input, after that I scroll page and focus is messed.

Comment: In Internet Explorer when you click on scroll bar focus leaving target input, in Mozila and others browsers all ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem: a focussed element loses focus when the IE scrollbar is used.

You'd need to:

- identify the element that loses focus
- identify when the document has been scrolled
- re-apply the focus

You can identify the element that loses focus through the `blur` event. Add a suitable event handler to every element where you want the focus to be remembered.

When the `blur` event handler runs, for a given input element, you should store, perhaps in global variable, an identifier for the input element. How you do this depends on how you choose to identify the element. The `id` of the element would be ideal.

You can tell when a document is being scrolled through the `scroll` event handler of the `window` object. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onscroll.

You can tell when a document has finished scrolling by comparing the before and after values of scrollHeight. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.scrollHeight.

Overall:

- add `blur` event handlers to your input elements
- on blur, note the element that loses focus and the current scrollHeight
- during scrolling, compare scrollHeights to determine if scrolling has stopped
- when scrolling has stopped, re-apply the focus

You may want to wait a short period between the scrolling having stopped and re-applying the focus. The user might be scrolling a little, stopping, scrolling, stopping. You don't want your script to cause crazy focus hopping behaviour.

Comment: Rather than capture `blur` on each and every `input` element, since this is an IE-specific problem, here's an IE-specific solution: Capture the [`focusout` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536936(v=vs.85).aspx) on a container of the elements (such as the form). Unlike `blur`, `focusout` bubbles on IE, so you can not only minimize the number of handlers you need to hook up, but play nicely with forms where you add/remove elements on the fly.